# Why am I unable to scrape the h1 tag by class?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I have the following code which should be scraping the h1 (with the class of c-page-title) text from a webpage using BeautifulSoup:

```
from requests import get
from requests.exceptions import RequestException
from contextlib import closing
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def simple_get(url):
    try:
        with closing(get(url, stream=True)) as resp:
            if is_good_response(resp):
                return resp.content
            else:
                return None

    except RequestException as e:
        log_error('Error during requests to {0} : {1}'.format(url, str(e)))
        return None


def is_good_response(resp):
    content_type = resp.headers['Content-Type'].lower()
    return (resp.status_code == 200
            and content_type is not None
            and content_type.find('html') > -1)


def log_error(e):
    print(e)


raw_html = simple_get('https://www.sonicsrising.com/2020/4/1/21201616/sonics-rising-is-on-hiatus')

html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'html.parser')

for h1 in html.select('h1'):
    if h1['class'] == 'c-page-title':
        print(h1.text)

for p in html.select('p'):
    print(p.text)
```

When I run it, it is able to pull the paragraphs from the 'p' tag but is not pulling the header with the class name.

Here is a screenshot of the HTML source from the page that shows the class name for the h1 tag I want to extract.

[image]

What am I doing wrong that is preventing that h1 from printing as well?

Thank you so much for your time and if there is anything I can add for clarity, please don't hesitate to ask and I will add it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it with the following code:

```
h1 = html.select('h1.c-page-title')[0].text.strip()
```